# Google+ parameters not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, schema, google-plus, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to get Google+ share link to display an image alongside personalized content but it's literally not working for me and it's driving me crazy; it should be a basic task.

I used the rich snippet generator on Google+ which generated some meta tags but my share link isn't picking up any of the data.

What am I doing wrong? It's not displaying the description or the image which I linked up in the Google plus share link.

Thanks

```
<!-- Update your html tag to include the itemscope and itemtype attributes. -->
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

<!-- Add the following three tags inside head. -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="Tamar">
<meta itemprop="description" content="dioshiofdhwai">
<img itemprop="image" src="www.onthisdayindigital.com/image1.png" />

<head>
<title>Tamar SEO, Social & Mobile | OnThisDayInDigital</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"> 
<link href="/icon.gif" type="image/ico" rel="icon">
<link rel="image_src" href="/icon.gif" />
    <!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>

<!-- Place this tag after the last share tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out, the Google+ service is really slow.
I logged on this morning to check my website and it was pulling the correct data.

You can use link to test the parameters https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

I expected more from google.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the issue, but I would point out that you didn't put them inside the `head` tag as the comment says you should. You put it before the tag.

Try moving this inside the tag and see if it works.

Comment: How did i miss that, regardless its still not working. Thanks for the input though